# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in FFmpeg Test Demo

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have a demo called FFMpegTest of Android which i downloaded from here..https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg..and i also have Library file of FFMpeg which is in this demo and i am using this Library in FFmpegTest..Now when i running..it gives java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.. Anyone have an idea about this..please share with me..Thanx in Advance..

which is in...VideoActivity.java

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,FFmpegListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnItemSelectedListener 
{
    private FFmpegPlayer mpegPlayer;
    private static boolean isSurfaceView = true;
    protected boolean mPlay = false;
    private View controlsView;
    private View loadingView;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    public View videoView;
    private Button playPauseButton;
    private boolean mTracking = false;
    private View streamsView;
    private Spinner languageSpinner;
    private int languageSpinnerSelectedPosition = 0;
    private Spinner subtitleSpinner;
    private int subtitleSpinnerSelectedPosition = 0;
    private StreamAdapter languageAdapter;
    private StreamAdapter subtitleAdapter;

    private FFmpegStreamInfo audioStream = null;
    private FFmpegStreamInfo subtitleStream = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        if (isSurfaceView)
            VideoActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.video_surfaceview);
        else
            VideoActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.video_view);

        seekBar = (SeekBar) this.findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        playPauseButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
        playPauseButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        controlsView = this.findViewById(R.id.controls);
        streamsView = this.findViewById(R.id.streams);
        loadingView = this.findViewById(R.id.loading_view);
        languageSpinner = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.language_spinner);
        subtitleSpinner = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.subtitle_spinner);

        languageAdapter = new StreamAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,new ArrayList<FFmpegStreamInfo>(), StreamAdapterType.AUDIO);
        languageAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        languageSpinner.setAdapter(languageAdapter);
        languageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        subtitleAdapter = new StreamAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,new ArrayList<FFmpegStreamInfo>(), StreamAdapterType.SUBTITLE);
        subtitleAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        subtitleSpinner.setAdapter(subtitleAdapter);
        subtitleSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        try
        {
            videoView = this.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
            //VideoActivity.this.mpegPlayer = new FFmpegPlayer((FFmpegDisplay)videoView, VideoActivity.this);
            this.mpegPlayer = new FFmpegPlayer((FFmpegDisplay)videoView, this);
            this.mpegPlayer.setMpegListener(this);
            setDataSource();

            //Too
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static enum StreamAdapterType
    {
        AUDIO, SUBTITLE
    };

    private static class StreamAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FFmpegStreamInfo>
    {

        private final StreamAdapterType adapterType;

        public StreamAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<FFmpegStreamInfo> objects, StreamAdapterType adapterType)
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.adapterType = adapterType;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            FFmpegStreamInfo item = getItem(position);
            Locale locale = item.getLanguage();

            String formatter;
            if (StreamAdapterType.AUDIO.equals(adapterType))
            {
                formatter = getContext().getString(R.string.language_spinner_drop_down);
            }
            else
            {
                formatter = getContext().getString(R.string.subtitle_spinner_drop_down);
            }
            String languageName = locale == null ? getContext().getString(R.string.unknown) : locale.getDisplayLanguage();
            String text = String.format(formatter, languageName);
            view.setText(text);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            CheckedTextView view = (CheckedTextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            FFmpegStreamInfo item = getItem(position);
            Locale locale = item.getLanguage();
            String languageName = locale == null ? getContext().getString(R.string.unknown) : locale.getDisplayLanguage();
            view.setText(languageName);
            return view;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.mpegPlayer.setMpegListener(null);
        this.mpegPlayer.stop();
        stop();
    }

    private void setDataSource() 
    {
        Log.d("url", "checin");
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // set font for ass
        File assFont = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Roboto.ttf");
        params.put("ass_default_font_path", assFont.getAbsolutePath());

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra(AppConstants.VIDEO_PLAY_ACTION_EXTRA_URL);
        Log.d("url", url);
        if (url == null) 
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("\"%s\" did not provided", AppConstants.VIDEO_PLAY_ACTION_EXTRA_URL));
        }
        if (intent.hasExtra(AppConstants.VIDEO_PLAY_ACTION_EXTRA_ENCRYPTION_KEY)) 
        {
            params.put("aeskey", intent.getStringExtra(AppConstants.VIDEO_PLAY_ACTION_EXTRA_ENCRYPTION_KEY));
        }

        this.playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        this.playPauseButton.setEnabled(true);
        mPlay = false;

        mpegPlayer.setDataSource(url, params, null, audioStream,subtitleStream);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        int viewId = v.getId();
        switch (viewId)
        {
            case R.id.play_pause:
            resumePause();
            return;

            default:
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFFUpdateTime(int currentTimeS, int videoDurationS, boolean isFinished)
    {
        if (!mTracking)
        {
            seekBar.setMax(videoDurationS);
            seekBar.setProgress(currentTimeS);
        }

        if (isFinished) 
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.dialog_end_of_video_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.dialog_end_of_video_message)
                    .setCancelable(true).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFFDataSourceLoaded(FFmpegError err, FFmpegStreamInfo[] streams) 
    {
        if (err != null) {
            String format = getResources().getString(
                    R.string.main_could_not_open_stream);
            String message = String.format(format, err.getMessage());

            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(VideoActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setOnCancelListener(
                            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                    VideoActivity.this.finish();
                                }
                            }).show();
            return;
        }
        playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        playPauseButton.setEnabled(true);
        this.controlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.streamsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        languageAdapter.clear();
        subtitleAdapter.clear();
        for (FFmpegStreamInfo streamInfo : streams) {
            CodecType mediaType = streamInfo.getMediaType();
            if (FFmpegStreamInfo.CodecType.AUDIO.equals(mediaType)) {
                languageAdapter.add(streamInfo);
            } else if (FFmpegStreamInfo.CodecType.SUBTITLE.equals(mediaType)) {
                subtitleAdapter.add(streamInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    private void displaySystemMenu(boolean visible) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            displaySystemMenu14(visible);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            displaySystemMenu11(visible);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @TargetApi(11)
    private void displaySystemMenu11(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            this.videoView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE);
        } else {
            this.videoView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(14)
    private void displaySystemMenu14(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            this.videoView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
        } else {
            this.videoView
                    .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
        }
    }

    public void resumePause() {
        this.playPauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        if (mPlay) {
            mpegPlayer.pause();
        } else {
            mpegPlayer.resume();
            displaySystemMenu(true);
        }
        mPlay = !mPlay;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFFResume(NotPlayingException result) {
        this.playPauseButton
                .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
        this.playPauseButton.setEnabled(true);

        displaySystemMenu(false);
        mPlay = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFFPause(NotPlayingException err) {
        this.playPauseButton
                .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        this.playPauseButton.setEnabled(true);
        mPlay = false;
    }

    private void stop() {
        this.controlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.streamsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.loadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFFStop() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFFSeeked(NotPlayingException result) 
    {
//      if (result != null)
//          throw new RuntimeException(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) 
    {
        if (fromUser) 
        {
            mpegPlayer.seek(progress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mTracking = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mTracking = false;
    }

    private void setDataSourceAndResumeState() {
        int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
        setDataSource();
        mpegPlayer.seek(progress);
        mpegPlayer.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
            View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        FFmpegStreamInfo streamInfo = (FFmpegStreamInfo) parentView
                .getItemAtPosition(position);
        if (parentView == languageSpinner) {
            if (languageSpinnerSelectedPosition != position) {
                languageSpinnerSelectedPosition = position;
                audioStream = streamInfo;
                setDataSourceAndResumeState();
            }
        } else if (parentView == subtitleSpinner) {
            if (subtitleSpinnerSelectedPosition != position) {
                subtitleSpinnerSelectedPosition = position;
                subtitleStream = streamInfo;
                setDataSourceAndResumeState();
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // if (parentView == languageSpinner) {
        // audioStream = null;
        // } else if (parentView == subtitleSpinner) {
        // subtitleStream = null;
        // } else {
        // throw new RuntimeException();
        // }
        // play();
    }

}
```

and this is my logcat :

```
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ffmpeg: findLibrary returned null
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     at roman10.ffmpegTest.VideoBrowser.<clinit>(VideoBrowser.java:37)
01-22 15:29:15.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1560):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: ...................................

Answer (score 1):

The above errors causes in FFmpegPlayer class. System.loadLibrary() can not find the native library. You should check the library path. Need to distinguish System.loadLibrary() and System.load().